# In Android, how to achieve this transition effect where incoming material elements expand into view?

Tags: android, android-transitions

As per Google's material design specs, under Animation - meaningful transitions

https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bzhp5Z4wHba3RXRFb0tRZEZDUUU/animation_meaninfultransitions_considerations_do.webm

Sometimes wish they could provide some sample codes right beside the design specs..

I couldn't find anything on google, probably because I am not sure what keywords to use.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked this library? It does a pretty good job. https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations

Comment: I found that too, but doesn't seem to have this particular animation where tapping on a list item expands it into view

Answer (score 0):

The example that you linked appears to be using a reveal transition animation with a shared element between two `Activities`. For details on how to get your feet wet, take a look at the Android training documentation on [Defining Custom Animations](http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html).